# Mixed type index signature with an optional specific value

Tags: typescript

I have an object that stores values related to other objects, keyed by their numeric id.

```
const values = {
  1: 0.5, // id 1
  2: 0.8, // id 2
}
```

However there is also a special exception key with the string id `'all'`, so the object could look like this:

```
const values = {
  'all': 0.3,
  1: 0.5,
  2: 0.8,
}
```

I've created `type ObjectId = number | 'all'` which works fine for passing the mixed type ids around my app, but doesn't work how I'd like in the index signature for typing the above values object. If I do what I've seen elsewhere for mixed type index signatures:

```
type ObjectId = number | 'all';

interface Values {
  [id in ObjectId]: number;
}
```

That compiles to

```
interface Values {
  [id: number]: number;
  'all': number;
}
```

Which makes the `'all'` property required, so an object like my first example would throw a type error.

How can I write an interface for this object that restricts keys to `numbers or the string 'all'` without making anything required?

Answer (score 0):

```js
interface Values {
  [id: number]: number;
  'all'?: number;
}

function foo(value: Values) {}

foo({
  1: 1,
});
foo({
  all: 1,
});
foo({
  1: 1,
  all: 1,
  other: 2, // will raise an error
});
```

make `all` optional?

Comment: This causes a new, different type error. In places where my object is accessed that are expecting a `number` value, it is now receiving `number | undefined` because if it's accessing the values with a key of type `ObjectId` it might be looking at the `all` key, and if `all` is optional it could be undefined.